# Verb for process:$X\implies Y$ that only increases symmetries: $G(X) \subset G(Y)$.

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, transformation, publishing

Let $X$, $Y$ be two objects, anything really. Suppose that some process, for instance a simple algorithm, converts $X$ into $Y$.  Suppose also that both $X$ and $Y$ have associated symmetry groups.  What is the verb describing this process if symmetries are (preserved, conserved, something else?): $G(X) \subset G(Y)$.  In other words $Y$ is constructed by the process, from $X$, and no symmetries are lost.  Please provide the best vocabulary term for describing that property.  Thanks. $G(X) = $ the symmetries of $X$.

Comment: In broad scene a map that perseveres a structure is called a morphism.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Just to be clear this is different from a homomorphism in algebra.  Also the set of all transformations of objects do not form a group, or at least not a useful one.  Is some type of category formed?

Comment: @QthePlatypus do you have a verb for describing those transformations of the objects?  I want to say that these transformations "blah" symmetries of the objects.

Comment: Yes this would form a category since this has an identity and composition works. 
 
I would say "map" and say "These transformation maps symmetries of the object".  And if I wanted to highlight the symmetries I would call them "Symmetry persevering maps".

Comment: @QthePlatypus What if these transformations aren't generally associative?

Comment: I have no proof but I suspect if the transformations are not associative they will be unable to preserve symmetry.